# What guitar setup to use to record on phone

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, homerecording, headphones

I have been playing guitar for a while now and I admit that I have been neglecting learning about the hardware. But now I would like to start recording what I play and preferably what I sing as well. I am looking for a setup where I can use my phone as a “Pseudo amp” where I can control the volume, tone, effects etc.

I realize there exist a few questions about this, but they all seem to suggest that you know a lot about mixers and producing. I am not looking for something to produce a professional sound by any means.

I just would like a setup where I can

- control stuff on my phone
- record what I play
- and then have a pair of headphones as an amp or a real amp (if I could switch between these it would be fantastic but headphones are the main priority).

So the solution would probably be something akin to a Line 6 Pod but preferably with the amp part controlled by the phone.

I don’t even know if it is technically possible but if the link between the phone and the headphones could be wireless that would be even better.

Hope you guys have some input and if nothing else then at least some input on what I need to read up on to find a good solution.

I know it might be expensive, that is OK it is a prioritized hobby!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This site discourages asking for and making recommendations of things like gear, books, etc. but you’ll be happy to know there are many devices out there that do what you are looking for, some for well under $100. Without knowing your setup and specifically what you want to achieve I suggest searching the web for “smartphone audio interface” or “smartphone guitar interface” to get an idea of what’s out there. Then call the customer service folks at Sweetwater.com (or another music store if you prefer). They can help you decide what is best for you based on the type of phone and musical gear you have, what you’re wanting to do, and your budget. Best of luck to you!